# After zipping a file, new size > old size * 100, how is it possible?

Tags: compression, zip

Our CEO asked it in a meeting and emphasized it's possible under normal conditions on every pc !

Comment: That's a vague question. When you say "zip", do you actually mean the "zip" compression tool? Which version? Which compression level? What kind of file? Obviously, compressing and already-compressed file may result in a larger file (due to the overhead of the compression algorithm and container), although not by this order of magnitude (unless old size is 1).

Comment: I suppose it will depend on the contents of the file being compressed. If each byte(?) is different then there's no "runs" to encode etc. Though this isn't a programming question really. Not sure where it should go (if anywhere).

Comment: every version of popular zip compression tools on every platform

Comment: Give us some more info about the file being compressed (original size, is it already compressed, type of data contained).

Comment: I don't know more. he said exactly what I asked here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure... Open notepad, enter a single character and save the file as `test.txt`. Then zip this file. The resultant zip file is (on my system) 149 bytes. Compression algorithms like ZIP consume overhead!

Comment: The same effect can be observed with larger files, but the ratio of old size to new size will be less.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how big a zip header is, but a dir full of 0 byte files would do the trick. Now move along.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy:

```
~$ echo > singlebyte
~$ ls -l singlebyte 
-rw-rw---- 1 sleske sleske 1 Nov  2 22:55 singlebyte
~$ zip singlebyte.zip singlebyte 
  adding: singlebyte (stored 0%)
~$ ls -l singlebyte.zip 
-rw-rw---- 1 sleske sleske 171 Nov  2 22:55 singlebyte.zip
```

Obviously, for small files the overhead will be considerable. Or what did you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically right (as others have already shown), but practically unimportant.